# The screen appears purple-ish after a fresh installation of elementary OS 7.1 alongside Windows, how can I fix it?

Tags: display, graphic-drivers

I installed elementary OS 7.1 alongside Windows on my computer, which has an AMD Radeon 6750 GRE graphics card. The colors appear correct on Windows, but the screen looks purple-ish on elementary OS. Any ideas on how to fix this issue? Appreciate the help.

[image]